# How to enable third party client authentication Asp .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-identity, identity

I'm developing a Web App with Asp .Net MVC 5 and this have normal ASP.NET Identity, but now I developed a Mobile App and I need authenticate users with my ASP app.

I'm tried to make an AJAX request to my Login method but the server response an exception: "***Validation of the provided anti-forgery token failed. The cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" and the form field "__RequestVerificationToken" were swapped.***" because I have ***[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]*** decorator, and I think that ASP .NET Identity has any other way to authenticate, but I don't know.

This is my login method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModdel model, string ReturnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Employer user = await _employerService.GetByCredentialsAsync(model.Email.Trim(), model.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            Employer existingEmail = await _employerService.GetByUsernameAsync(model.Email);
            if (existingEmail == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "El usuario no está registrado. Regístrate o intenta ingresar con un nuevo usuario");
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(new { statusCode = 400, message = "El usuario no está registrado. Regístrate o intenta ingresar con un nuevo usuario", Success = "False" });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Contraseña inválida. Intenta de nuevo");
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return Json(new { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, Success = "False" });
            }
        }
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReturnUrl))
        ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home");

    return Json(new { statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, returnUrl = ReturnUrl });
}
```

And this is my ConfigureAuth:

```
// For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            //Custom provirder create to read language fomr URL
            CookieAuthenticationProvider provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
            var originalHandler = provider.OnApplyRedirect;
            provider.OnApplyRedirect = context =>
            {

                var mvcContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(mvcContext);

                //Get the current language  
                RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

                //Reuse the RetrunUrl
                Uri uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
                string returnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)[context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter];
                routeValues.Add(context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter, returnUrl);
                routeValues.Add(Cross.Constants.ModalRouteValue, Cross.Constants.LoginModal);
                //Overwrite the redirection uri
                UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                string NewURI = url.Action("Index", "Home", routeValues);

                //Overwrite the redirection uri
                context.RedirectUri = NewURI;
                originalHandler.Invoke(context);
            };

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index?Modal=Login"),
                Provider = provider,
            });

            // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what code do you have?  How have you configured ASP.Net Identity?  How do you make the request to login, and what are you expecting to get back?

Comment: @BrendanGreen thanks, I edited the question adding my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking your MVC application is only good for working in a browser. If you need to provide a third party with some data and that is not happening through the browser, you will need to use [WebApi](https://www.asp.net/web-api). And there you can use [bearer token authentication](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) for your clients.